# Flash Builder: Loading app to iPhone

Tags: apache-flex, testing, flash-builder, itunes

Over the last few hours, I have been attempting to load my Flex SDK/Flash Builder application onto my iPhone. I have tried numerous things and nothing seems to be working. When I import the .ipa to iTunes and attempt to sync it to my phone, everything goes right until at the last moment it says Failed to sync 'my app'. When I set up the Run in Flash Builder, I set the Certificate to my iOS Developer Certificate in P12 format, and I set the Provisioning Profile to my iOS Team Provisioning Profile.

I thought that this process would take 5 minutes, but now it seems like it has been 5 hours.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Nevermind! I figured it out!!! I was using the wrong profiles :)

Comment: Please post a formal answer to your own question; as it will help others.  I'm glad you got it working.

Answer (score 1):

Went through the same thing myself a week ago.  iOS provisioning profiles come in two flavors

- developer provisioning profile (used for internal or ad hoc testing on specific test devices)
- and distribution provisioning profile (used when you are ready to submit to Apple)

to load an iOS app onto your device for testing, just make sure you download and use the developer provisioning profile (when I download them I have started a process whereby I include *dist* or *dev* in the name of the provisioning file so its clear which is which.

Im eagerly awaiting my first approved (fingers crossed app any minute now since I learned they approve apps over the weekends as well.

good luck with your app.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. That is what worked for me. Good luck with your app as well.